# Is it possible to show TextSelection with an Icon Font?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, textselection, icon-fonts

I need to use Font Awesome in an WYSIWYG Editor, and want to, that the user can highlight the Icon with Text Selection.

I tried to `user-select: all`, but it doesn't work (The Icon is still not markable, when I select the text)

```css
.select-text {
  user-select: all !important;
}

.select-text::selection {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p>
    <span class="select-text">Hello </span>
    <span class="fa fa-check select-text"></span>
    <span class="select-text"> World</span>
</p>
```

Is this possible?

---

I have found a workaround, see below. I am still happy about an answer on how to do this without the unicode with the `:before` selector class `fa-check`. Is this probably the reason? I tried:

```
.select-text:before::selection {
    background: red !important;
}
.select-text:before {
    user-select: element !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, as a workaround, I can use the [Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/) and use the Unicode (e.g. `&#xf00c;`) instead of the class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p>
    <span class="fa">&#xf00c;</span>
</p>
```

<sub>As this is a workaround, I am still happy about an answer on how to do this without the unicode with the `:before` selector class `fa-check`.</sub>